# Tensorflow error "shape Tensorshape() must have rank 1"

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
cur_dir = os.getcwd()

def modify_image(image):
  #resized = tf.image.resize_images(image, 180, 180, 3)
   image.set_shape([32,32,3])
   flipped_images = tf.image.flip_up_down(image)
   return flipped_images

def read_image(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
  key,value = reader.read(filename_queue)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value)
  return key,image

def inputs():
 filenames = ['standard_1.jpg', 'standard_2.jpg' ]
 filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
 filename,read_input = read_image(filename_queue)
 reshaped_image = modify_image(read_input)
 reshaped_image = tf.cast(reshaped_image, tf.float32)
 label=tf.constant([1])
 return reshaped_image,label

def weight_variable(shape):
 initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
 return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
 initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
 return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
 return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
 return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,32,32,3])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
image,label=inputs()
image=tf.reshape(image,[-1,32,32,3])
label=tf.reshape(label,[-1,1])
image_batch=tf.train.batch([image],batch_size=2)
label_batch=tf.train.batch([label],batch_size=2)

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

image_4d=x_image = tf.reshape(image, [-1,32,32,3])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(image_4d, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([8 * 8 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 8*8*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 2])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([2])

y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
cross_entropy= -tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(image_batch[1],tf.float32)*tf.log(y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(20000):
 sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:image_batch[0:1],y_:label_batch[0:1]})
```

I am trying to run the tensorflow convolutional model over my own images of dimension of[32x32x3] images. The images are being read properly and are being assigned to the placeholder, during training. The problem arises during running the train_step op. When I execute the graph I get the following error.

```
TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(1), Dimension(32), Dimension(32), Dimension(3)]) must have rank 1
```

But when I see the example [here](https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/5_convolutional_net.py), the images are in the form of [batch_size,height,width,depth] tensors only. And this example works fine. 
Am I missing anything?

Comment: This question still manages to be useful, but contains *way* more code than is necessary to demonstrate the problem - and it's now difficult to trim it down to just the failed slicing operation because the answer addresses other bits of the posted code irrelevant to the question asked. Please trim your code down to a minimal example next time; this didn't need 8 lines to reproduce, let alone 80.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the error is coming from this line:

```
cross_entropy= -tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(image_batch[1],tf.float32)*tf.log(y_conv))
```

`image_batch` is a 5-D tensor, with shape `[2, 1, 32, 32, 3]`, where 2 is the `batch_size` argument to `tf.train.batch()`, and the 1 was added by the earlier `image = tf.reshape(image, [-1, 32, 32, 3])`. (**N.B.** This reshape is unnecessary, since `tf.train.batch()` already adds a batch dimension, and you end up having to *undo* the effect of the reshape when you later construct `image_4d`).

In TensorFlow, the slicing operation (i.e. `image_batch[1]`) is slightly less flexible than in NumPy. The number of dimensions specified in the slice must be equal to the rank of the tensor: i.e. you must specify all five dimensions for this to work. You could specify `image_batch[1, :, :, :, :]` to get a 4-D slice of `image_batch`.

I noticed a few other issues in your program, however:

1. The `cross_entropy` calculation seems strange. Typically this uses a predicted label and compares it to the known *label*, as opposed to the image data.
2. The feed on the training step seems to have no effect, because placeholders `x` and `y_` are unused in your program. Furthermore, you appear to be feeding a `tf.Tensor` (indeed, an illegal slice of `image_batch`), so this will fail when you execute that statement. If you intend to use feeding, you should feed in NumPy arrays holding the input data.
3. If you're not using feeding—i.e. using the `tf.WholeFileReader` as shown in your program—you will need to call `tf.train.start_queue_runners()` to get started. Otherwise your program will hang, waiting for input.