# ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (10, 20, 50, 50, 1)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

My model

```
model.add(Conv3D(nb_filters[0], kernel_dim1=nb_conv[0], 
kernel_dim2=nb_conv[0], kernel_dim3=nb_conv[0],
input_shape=(20, 50, 50,1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0])))
model.add(Conv3D(nb_filters[1], kernel_dim1=nb_conv[0], 
kernel_dim2=nb_conv[0], kernel_dim3=nb_conv[0],activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0])))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes,init='normal'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adadelta',
metrics['accuracy'])
```

My input numpy arrays

```
train_data=np.load('D:/muchdata-50-50-20.npy')
train=train_data[-10:]
test=train_data[-2:]
train1 = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,20,50,50,1)
y_train =  [i[1] for i in train]
testx=np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,20,50,50,1)
testy=[i[1] for i in test]
```

Here's the preprocessing function

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True,
featurewise_std_normalization=True,
rotation_range=20,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)
```

Here's the fit

```
datagen.fit(train1)
```

when I try run i get the error like this[image]

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673874/tensorflow-error-shape-tensorshape-must-have-rank-1

Comment: @putonspectacles i don't understand how to use that on this code...bcoz my conv3d input_data expects (20,50,50,1)......if u know how pls edit my code and post it

Answer (score 0):

For image data generator, image shape should be set with rank 4. So, I think your reshape command should be altered (my suggestion). For reshape `-1`, this actually means "convert the multi-dimension into one dimension".